# Reinterpret 2d array as pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Assume I have an array like this:

```
unsigned char a[10][10];
```

and I want to use fread to read bytes into this array (row-major order):

```
FILE *f = fopen("xxx.bin", "rb");
fread((unsigned char *)a, 1, 10 * 10, f);
fclose(f);
```

As the first parameter of fread is of type `void *`, is there a standard way to convert `unsigned char a[10][10]` to `void *`? Should I use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or? As 2d-arrays in c++ are allocated consecutively, I think it is reasonable to reinterpret it as pointers.

Comment: `std::fread(a, sizeof(*a), sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a), f);` if you're remotely interested in reading these row-at a time with any chance of sub-row failure (which you really should be validating by checking your return results). Not sure why you're doing this with C apis, but to each their own. best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a `void*` pointing at `a`, just take its address (`&a`) and let the compiler do the implicit conversion to `void*`:

```
fread(&a, sizeof a, 1, f);
```

There are a few caveats/notes:

- Firstly, you take the pain to close the file, but you fail to check for read errors.
- Whenever you use reinterpret_cast, the only way to use the result is to reinterpret_cast it back to the exact former type. In general, you don't use reinterpret_cast therefore, unless you need to e.g. store a pointer in an integer. static_cast is the way to go, as others mentioned.
- Never use C-style cast. They are dangerous and they don't document what's going on at all. FWIW, you could const-decorate your array and your code would happily compile and break at runtime, because you overrode the safety-switch of the compiler.
- I wouldn't count on having no padding between the rows of the matrix, i.e. its size wouldn't be just 100. You can only solve that using separate read operations for each row. I'm not sure about this point though, it could well be that its size is guaranteed to not include any padding.

Comment: Arrays are guaranteed to have no padding

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense not to allow padding, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Almost correct but if `a` is already an array (either 1D, or 2D or ...) beware : **in C or C++ an array is already a pointer**. So in the example the correct expression is `fread(a, sizeof a, 1, f);`. `&a` is a `char **` and the data will not go where expected !

Comment: @SergeBallesta Actually not. An array identifier **decays** into a pointer in almost all contexts, but it **is not** a pointer. This is not just nitpicking, it has very important consequences. For instance, it is the reason why `(intptr_t)a` and `(intptr_t)&a` have the same value if `a` is an array. Guaranteed.

Comment: @cmaster: Thanks for the precision, I thought I was still in the 80's with K&R C :-). But as there is no explicit cast of `a` in the answer, and as fread takes a `void *` how the hell the compiler could guess we want `&a` to be `a` in `fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, f);`?

Comment: The type of `&a` is pointer to an array of ten arrays of ten integers. In short, it is a pointer to something, which implicitly converts to a pointer to void. The fact that arrays decay into pointers in many contexts is completely irrelevant. Note that the reason I didn't use array decay (which is technically the same) is that you could substitute `a` with pretty much anything and the code would still work!

Answer (score 1):

The following works in gcc 4.8.2:

```
FILE *f = fopen("xxx.bin", "rb");
fread(a, sizeof(unsigned char), 10 * 10, f);
fclose(f);
```

If you prefer explicit casts, then standard way is to use `static_cast`. It should be used because it preserves address when casting to `void*`.

```
FILE *f = fopen("xxx.bin", "rb");
fread(static_cast<void*>(a), sizeof(unsigned char), 10 * 10, f);
fclose(f);
```

`reinterpret_cast` only guarantees that if you cast something to `void*` and then cast back to your type, then you will get the same value.

Comment: @cmaster Conversion from [cv] `T*` to [cv] `void*` is implicit.  Just conversion the other way is not.